# Not able to Remove previously inserted UI

Tags: r

in the below app, I am not able to remove previously inserted UI. Not sure why. Could anyone please help...............................................................

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
```r

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Insert and Remove UI

```{r}

actionButton("add", "Add UI")
actionButton("rmv", "Remove UI")
 observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#add",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = textInput(paste0("txt", input$add),
                     "Insert some text"),multiple = FALSE
    )
  })
 observeEvent(input$rmv, {
    removeUI(
      selector = "div:has(< #txt)"
    )
  })
```

```
````

Comment: Thanks. It is almost working. but it is removing only the last operation. (Sorry my bad). What if I need all the previous operations? Also, it is removing only textbox and title is as it is.(It not removed)

Answer (score 0):

We can get the previous ids using `seq_len(input$add)` where `input$add` is 1,2,3,... etc, then construct a [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/has/) statment using `paste0` and `sprintf`

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}



  ### Insert and Remove UI

actionButton("add", "Add UI")
actionButton("rmv", "Remove UI")
observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#add",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = textInput(paste0("txt", input$add),
                     sprintf("Insert some text for %i",input$add)),multiple = FALSE
    )
  })
observeEvent(input$rmv, {
    removeUI(
      #Remove the last UI
      #selector = sprintf("div:has(> #txt%i)",input$add),
      #Remove all previous UIs
      selector = sprintf("div:has(%s)",paste0('> #txt', seq_len(input$add), collapse = ",")),
      immediate = TRUE,
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
```
````

## Update

Remove the last UI every time user click *Remove UI*

```
### Insert and Remove UI

actionButton("add", "Add UI")
actionButton("rmv", "Remove UI")
data = reactiveValues(tmp=0)
observeEvent(input$add, {
    data$tmp <- c(data$tmp,input$add)

    insertUI(
      selector = "#add",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = textInput(paste0("txt", input$add),
                     sprintf("Insert some text for %i",input$add)),multiple = FALSE
    )
  })

observeEvent(input$rmv, {
    rm <- tail(data$tmp, 1)
    data$tmp <- setdiff(data$tmp, rm)

    removeUI(
      #Remove the last UI
      #selector = sprintf("div:has(> #txt%i)",input$add),
      #Remove all previous UIs
      selector = sprintf("div:has(%s)",paste0('> #txt', rm, collapse = ",")),
      immediate = TRUE,
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
```

Comment: @Suliman, Small doubt when I replace ````textInput```` by ````fileInput```` why remove UI is not working. It should work right?

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not the same try `fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
        accept = c(
          "text/csv",
          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
          ".csv")
        )` and `textInput(paste0("txt", 1),
                      sprintf("Insert some text for %i",1))` in R.

Comment: Hi, Is this the solution ? I mean should I replace the above code?

Comment: NO, `textInput` and `fileInput` they have different HTML structures as you can see when you print them in R console. Probably you should post a new question and add `shiny` and `jQuery` as tags

Comment: I have added the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59235852/issues-while-displaying-the-dataset-and-unloading-previous-operations